# C++ compiler - Unknown type name after migration to Swift 3

Tags: c++, swift3, xcode8

I am trying to migrate to Swift 3 from 2.3 and I got some issues for some pods I use. There is some Unknown type name 'template' issue, but before Swift 3 it works good.

template bool NearlyEqual(T x, T y, T tolerance) {
  T diff = x - y;
  return diff <= tolerance && -diff <= tolerance;
}

So there are also a lot of other Tesseract issues:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it was connected to some derived data or other issue I cleaned it alt+shift+cmd+k but it did not help me, but when I clicked on Product (top Xcode's menu) and then holder alt key and clicked Clean build folder.. it helped me. Strange issue.

Comment: Might want to close it on GitHub, too. https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/issues/296